# Disorganized numbers

Tags: pattern

What's the answer to this puzzle?

---

```
          3121725189161013227144198245112151202662321

          Key:(21271521191722) (..,.,.,..,..,..,..,..)
      
          Answer: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Comment: Are the dots in `..,.,.,..,..,..,..,..` supposed to be rot13(qvtvgf)?

Comment: @Someone They're more like directives.

Comment: What do you mean by "directives"?

Comment: @Someone I just meant it tells you what to do

Comment: Is the answer in letters or numbers?

Comment: @Someone That's up to you guys to figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> ALPHABET

First thing we can do is to

> map the Key to the dots: (21, 2, 7, 15, 21, 19, 17, 22)

At this point, we would consider that

> each number is the position of a letter, but not in normal alphabet

Then looking at the first string, we find that

> Each number between 1 and 26 are there, but not in correct order. The fun part is to separate digits

To do this, we use a bit of logic

> For example there is ..144... in the string. 44 is not in 1..26, so we can isolate the second 4. Same for 266. We can isolate the second 6, then the 26 just before since 6 alone should appear one only

And finally we get the following table:

> 3 12 17 25 18 9 16 10 13 22 7 14 4 19 8 24 5 11 2 15 1 20 26 6 23 21

> We can use this table for each number of the key, to get the  number: 21th number is 1, which remaps to A in A1-Z26 coding

> and so all until making the word ALPHABET

Comment: Outstanding. I couldn't get past figuring out the key-to-dots bit.

Comment: Correct, well done!